# Searching with Elasticsearch filters

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, search

I am using elasticsearch to do my search queries. An example would be to search for "graduates" and filter it by topics e.g. "Planit Training".

Here is what the logic looks like now in views.py:

```
responses = ResponseDocument20.search().filter(Q_ES("match", Response=cleanQ.lower())&Q_ES("match", Topic__Name=queryT)).extra(size=10000)
```

However the topic filter, "Q_ES("match", Topic__Name=queryT)" is matching anything that has "Planit" in it, such as "Previous Planit Assignments" or "Planit Bootcamp", so it is returning extra results that i do not want.

How would i query it so it only returns results that are linked to "Planit Training" only?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Using "match_phrase" instead